Word to describe telling yourself that you are not, and will never be, good enough
If you are saying to yourself things like:

You messed up this job.
You are not good enough.
It is your fault.
You are the reason this happened.

What's a word for when you are doing this to yourself?

To be hypercritical, self-blaming, harshest critic, put yourself down…

Can you edit your question and add a sentence where you would use this word/expression?

Oh no, it's an unregistered user which usually means they are not coming back... pity.

There's not one word for everything. There are a lot of 'self-' words for this.

There’s always the possibility that it is a correct self-assessment.

Such a person is self-condemnatory. OED lists the adjective.

self-condemnation [noun; non-count]

the act or habit of condemning (= strongly criticizing) yourself                                                                                        [Cambridge Dictionary]



self-condemnation [noun]

the blaming of oneself for something.                [ODE; courtesy of Google]



self-condemnation [noun]

the act or an instance of condemning one's own character or actions ...
                                                                                           [Merriam-Webster]



What is self condemnation?
Well it is your own voice internalised; self talk that commentates
negatively on your value, person-hood, actions, feelings and
behaviours. Common experiences of self condemnation would be, "You are
stupid, unacceptable, weak". "You are sinful, unworthy, a fraud". "You
are unforgiven, unlovable, a failure".
...
Of course self condemnation is not a disassociated habit, it stems
from poor self image, guilt, childhood labels, shame, critical
parenting and a number of other
sources.                                                        [Will Van Der Har; Mind and
Soul] [re-ordered]



Don't let self-condemnation take hold — anger, depression, and distress from the past can cripple your ability to thrive in the
present.       [Jason Wilson; courtesy of
Google]



In the same vein : self-flagellation (extreme criticism of oneself)

With dictionary support, worth an 'answer'.

You are engaging in negative self talk.
Self talk is

an internal dialogue in which an individual utters phrases or sentences to themself

Negative self talk

often confirms and reinforces negative beliefs and attitudes, such as fears and false aspirations, which have a correspondingly negative effect on the individual’s feelings (e.g., a sense of worthlessness)

APA Dictionary

I was looking for this answer -- imo it characterizes the activity that OP describes quite precisely. If we need a verb instead of a noun, I think that ruminating covers much of the same ground; it can describe over-thinking more generally, but often has this connotation of self-blame. Worth noting that both words are in the jargon of therapy-speak, which, although recently popular in casual conversation in some demographics, may not work in all contexts.

Ruminating might have more of a sense of "thinking a similar pattern of thoughts over and over again", rather than specifically negative and defeated thoughts. A lot of ruminating takes the form, "I should have done X", and doesn't carry a sense of "I'll never be good enough". I'd say "using negative self-talk" to get a verb phrase. Edit: Re-reading the above comment, we mostly agree.

I think this answer gets at a generally good point WRT English: oftentimes even when there is a single word to describe something a phrase will do a better job of providing precision or clarity.

In general, I'd call the attitude described by the OP...

Defeatism (Full Oxford English Dictionary)
Behaviour or attitudes indicating that one expects defeat or failure, or that one is ready to accept it; defeatist behaviour or attitude.

...but in contexts where someone has just said something defeatist, such as "I'll never be good enough to succeed at my new job", I might say...

That's a self-fulfilling prophecy


It's not just one word, but it sounds like you are describing "impostor syndrome".

Impostor syndrome is more specific than what OP is asking. Someone who has impostor syndrome has the symptoms that are described in the question, but someone who has the symptoms that are described in the question does not necessarily have impostor syndrome.

@AccidentalTaylorExpansion: "Telling yourself that you are not good enough" might easily not be impostor syndrome, but "telling yourself that you will never be good enough" — see the question's title — sounds very much like impostor syndrome.

On the other hand, if I tell myself that I will never be a great concert pianist, I'm simply being honest, but this kind of thing doesn't seem to be what the OP is talking about.

Catastrophizing perhaps

Catastrophizing means that a person fixates on the worst possible
outcome and treats it as likely, even when it is not

Relevant article

I think catastrophizing is a poor fit here; it really describes one's attitude towards upcoming events, whereas OP's statements are about current state and past events.

@StevenStadnicki Perhaps, but assuming that feeling inadequate now means you'll never be good enough is a form of catastrophizing. And OP clearly suggests that in the title of the question.

This describes someone with an inferiority complex.

Inadequate, as in "I'm an inadequate human being".
It's an unfortunate attitude to have about oneself but I'm sure most people feel that way from time to time and sometimes frequently.

This doesn't really work: The OP is looking to describe the criticism itself.

These types of internal negative feelings about yourself can colloquially be called stinking thinking. It is a pervasive mindset of negativity about oneself, which is often overblown and counterproductive.
